# Appcache manifest giving 404 in Firefox's validation tool

Tags: html, firefox, html5-appcache

I am trying to get HTML5 AppCache working.

I have a prototype site which is structured as follows:

- The main HTML page that I want to be available offline is at `/offlineDemo/`.
- The resource files are in `/lib/offlineDemo/js/`, `/lib/offlineDemo/css/`, etc.
- The cache manifest file is at `/lib/offlineDemo/assets/offlineDemo.appcache`.
- The HTML page begins with:
  `<html manifest='/lib/offlineDemo/assets/offlineDemo.appcache'>`
  (after the doctype of course).

This seems to be working fine in Chrome. Having loaded the page once, I can disconnect the network and I'm still able to reload it without any problems.

However on Firefox it's not working. I'm trying to debug it using the dev tools command-line, and odd things are happening.

- Typing `appcache list` shows me a list of all the files in my site except for the main HTML page itself. The files that are listed show with file size 0 and don't appear to have actually been cached.
- Typing `appcache validate` gives me a list of errors relating to trying to parse a 404 page as a manifest file. It appears to be trying to validate a manifest file at the following URL: `/offlineDemo//lib/offlineDemo/assets/offlineDemo.appcache`

  ie it's appending the manifest URL to the end of the page's URL without considering the fact that I've defined the manifest as an absolute URL. Obviously the URL it is trying to load is invalid and gives a 404.

This doesn't seem like correct behaviour so I'm guessing it may be a Firefox bug, especially as it is working fine in Chrome. However all the examples I've found for AppCache show a relative URL in the html manifest attribute, so that leaves me wondering.

So my questions are:

- Are absolute URLs valid for referencing a manifest file?
- If they are, why is it not working in Firefox?
- If they're not, why not, and is there a work-around?
- Or am I just doing something stupid and mis-interpreting the debug info?

Comment: If you change it to a relative path, does it work?  Is there any reason you need a root relative path, do you plan on moving the index page around?

Comment: @robertc: thanks for the response. The framework I'm using likes to have static assets in the lib area, so the manifest does need to be in a separate path to the main page. However I've changed the manifest path to be `../lib/offlineDemo/etc` in the HTML and this does now seem to load the file correctly. Its still not working though: `appcache validate` is now throwing errors on all the URLs in the manifest file itself (they're all absolute and start `/lib/offlineDemo/...`). Do I need to make those relative as well? And if so, relative to what?

Comment: The specification requires a [valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#attr-html-manifest), with URL parsing as defined [in this spec](http://url.spec.whatwg.org/).  From skimming, it definitely looks like a Firefox bug.

One other thing that might be causing difficulties: you have the home page as the default document `/` instead of (for example) `/index.html`, if you access the root document by the full filename does it work?

Comment: Oh, and URLs in the manifest file can be absolute, [there's specific examples in the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#some-sample-manifests), I suspect the bug you've uncovered in Firefox is to do with starting from the directory rather than a specific file as mentioned above.

Comment: @robertc: hmm, the same seems to be happening regardless of whether I include the index page name or not. Chrome continues to work just fine. Interestingly, IE11 also doesn't seem to be working for me, but I don't know of any dev tool features I can use to analyse it in IE11, so it may be the same issue or something completely different.

Comment: Probably worth clearing the appcache and starting again at this point.  Can you get anything online so I can investigate further?

Comment: @robertc: Thanks, I'll give it a go. I can't get anything online immediately as it's dependent on this internal framework lib, but if it's still a problem later in the week when I have a bit of free time I'll try to put together a minimal stand-alone version.

Comment: @robertc: An update: If I move both the html file and the manifest file into the site root, everything now works fine in firefox; the absolute urls to /lib/... in the manifest work just fine. However, putting either or both of those files into a subdirectory, and having absolute URLs in the manifest causes firefox to barf with messages like `/lib/offlineDemo/css/demo.css points to a resource that is not available`. I'm fairly sure this behaviour is broken. I'm going to have to put up a working demo.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure there is a bug here, we're at the stage of working around the bug in the least kludgy way ;)

Comment: @robertc: I've posted a blog entry going into all the issues I found while working in AppCache. If you're interested, you can read it here: http://spudley.com/blog/appcache-trials-and-tribulations